# Error: Cannot read property 'find' of null

Tags: angular

I'm having an issue with my app. I've separated my question form into 2 separate components, one for **single-answer** and one for **multiple-answer**.

I'm getting an error message

> "Error: Cannot read property 'find' of null"

when navigating from second to third question. The `"answers"` variable is null and it seems like the answer(s) are not getting passed from the question components to the quiz component and not getting pushed to the answers array.
This seems to be affecting the display of explanation text, navigation doesn't navigate past the second question and scoring is not working.
Please could you see my Stackblitz: **https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-10-quiz-app** and help to fix this issue. Thank you.

question component:

```
<ng-content></ng-content>

<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <question-single-answer [question]="question"></question-single-answer>
  <question-multiple-answer [question]="question"></question-multiple-answer>
</form>
```

code that gives the error in quiz component:

```
  checkIfAnsweredCorrectly(): void {
    if (this.question) {
      const correctAnswerFound = this.answers.find((answer) => {
        return this.question.options &&
          this.question.options[answer] &&
          this.question.options[answer]['selected'] &&
          this.question.options[answer]['correct'];
      });

      const answers = this.isAnswered() ? this.answers.map((answer) => answer + 1) : [];
      this.quizService.userAnswers.push(this.isAnswered() ? answers : this.answers);

      this.addUpScores(answers, correctAnswerFound);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can add check  if(this.answers.hasOwnProperty("find")){ //here your code }

Answer (score 1):

In the StackBlitz URL you have provided, it seems you are assigning the variable `answers` an empty array of numbers in the beginning.

Later on, `this.answers` to `null` in multiple places like the function `advanceToNextQuestion` and the `advanceToPreviousQuestion` functions. After which, most probably the `checkIfAnsweredCorrectly` function is getting called where you are getting this error.

Please verify your logic again. It is a logical error.

Comment: I commented out the this.answers = null in advanceToNextQuestion and advanceToPreviousQuestion and the navigation seems to work now in Stackblitz, but not locally, still getting the find error.

Comment: I copied the code from Stackblitz locally and now navigation works and I'm not getting the find error. When I console.log this.answers I'm getting the empty array. I need the answers to get pushed to the this.answers array.

Comment: When I shuffle the questions and reach the multiple-answer question, the options seem to highlight all red, not sure why this is happening.